# Identifying breaks in consecutive values in R

Tags: r, loops, count, time-series

I have a data frame in R similar to the one below where the columns are year- and week number, and every row is a specific person. To get the relevant input data on the specific ID's I have an indicator of, whether the person was unemployed in 2015 or 2016 `IND15`and `IND16`. If the observation is '1' the person is unemployed, and if the observation is '0', the person is employed:

```
ID  y12_01  y12_02  y12_03  y12_04... y12_51  y12_52 y13_01 IND12 IND13  
01    1       1       1       0         0       1        1    1    1   
02    1       1       1       1         1       1        1    1    1   
03    0       0       1       1         0       0        1    1    1
```

As you see in the examples above, some of the rows shows unemployment in both 2012 and 2013. If the person has a sequence only of unemployment (only 1) beginning in 2015, I would like to create an indicator of this, and if the person has a 'break' in the sequence (i.e. ID01 or ID03), I would like to create an indicator of this.

I suspect part of the solution could include rowSums or a while-loop, but I have not had any luck so far. In SAS I think one would perhaps be able to use the array function, but once again I am not quite sure of how this would be done in R-language.

Comment: I think this will be a lot easier to work with if you have a long file with `ID, year, month, unemployment_flag` columns. Then you just do a 'group by' operation using any number of R functions (`aggregate`, the `dplyr` package, `data.table` package) etc. Working in wide format with something akin to SAS' array code would be overly complicated. In fact, I'd probably do the same in SAS - `proc transpose` then `proc sql + group by` against a long-form datafile.

Comment: Are there any caveats to transposing? When I have created the indicators I need, I will delete all the yyy_ww columns and join a data frame with background information. I could always transpose it back when I'm done with the indicators though. It is already a 'long' dataset in the sense  that I have around 700.000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question, try `df[df$IND15 == 1 & df$IND16 == 1, "Indicator1"] <- 1`.

For the second part, you should be able to do it with a for loop:

```
for (ID in df$ID){
  if (any(df[ID, 1:x]) == 0){
    df[ID, "Indicator2"] <- 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't I have defined the x beforehand?

Comment: x would just be the number of columns you have to look at. It looks like you could replace it with `ncol(df) - 2`, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to retain the wide format, one way to create the indicator would be to multiply the columns. Using the following example data,

```
d <- read.table(text = "ID  y12_01  y12_02  y12_03  y12_04  y12_51  y12_52 y13_01 IND15 IND16  
01    1       1       1       0         0       1        1    1    1   
02    1       1       1       1         1       1        1    1    1   
03    0       0       1       1         0       0        1    1    1", 
  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

where the relevant columns are assumed to be columns 2 to 7, and the values are assumed to be numeric, we can create an `indic` column

```
d$indic <- Reduce(`*`, d[, 2:7])
d
#   ID y12_01 y12_02 y12_03 y12_04 y12_51 y12_52 y13_01 IND15 IND16 indic
# 1  1      1      1      1      0      0      1      1     1     1     0
# 2  2      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     1     1     1
# 3  3      0      0      1      1      0      0      1     1     1     0
```

Comment: 1) Is there any reason for you to make it as text?
2) Multiplying could definitely work for part of it, but I would come out with a 0 if a person started their unemployment sequence in i.e. `y12_51`and it continues in 2013, right?